# Regex to match everything [string_string] exept when both words are full caps

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that will match a combination of 2 strings seperated by a underscore encapsulated by []. Every instance must be matched, exept when both strings are completely uppercase words.

What I got till now is:

```
\[(([A-z](?=[a-z]+))(?!=[a-z]{0,}))[a-zA-Z]+_(([A-z](?![a-z]+))(?!=[a-z]{0,}))[a-zA-Z]+\]
```

it should match everything exept situations like these:

```
[ONLYCAPS_ONLYCAPSTOO]
```

Thanks in advance!

Forgot to mention: the strings can also contain special characters and whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use negative look-ahead in this situation. Following regex would work:

```
\[(?![A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\])[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+\]
```

**Break up:**

```
\[           # Start with '['
   (?!         # See if not followed by
      [A-Z]+     # Upper case letters one or more times
       _         # An underscore
      [A-Z]+     # Upper case letters one or more times
      \]         # Till the ending ']'
   )           # Negative look-ahead ends
   # If negative look-ahead succeeds, perform actual match.
   [a-zA-Z]+   # Match upper or lowercase alphabets one or more times
    _          # An underscore
   [a-zA-Z]+   # Match upper or lowercase alphabets one or more times
\]           # Ending ']'
```

Comment: this works nearly the way it has to, i forgot to mention that it must also match strings with special characters (exept the _ becouse it can  only occure once). but i will accept this in a second becouse of the great explaination about why i would do it this way.

Comment: @BartKuijer Whatever special characters you want to match, you can put it in character class - `[a-zA-Z]+`. Or if you're not sure what all special characters to match, just use `[^_]+` to match any character except the `_`.

Answer (score 2):

You should do it this way

```
(?!\[[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\])\[[^_]+_[^_]+\]
--------------------- --------------
         |                   |->desired result
         |
         |->won't match further if there's [ONLYCAPS_ONLYCAPSTOO] ahead
```

---

`(?!pattern)` is a zero width lookahead..i.e it would only check but not match!

`[^_]` would match anything except `_`

Comment: An explanation would be useful (or at least state that it follows the same logic as another poster's answer, but is different in a specific way).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex with negative lookahead (if lookarounds are supported in your regex tool):

```
(?!^\[[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\]$)\[(([A-z](?=[a-z]+))(?!=[a-z]{0,}))[a-zA-Z]+_(([A-z](?![a-z]+))(?!=[a-z]{0,}))[a-zA-Z]+\]
```